# Can we have the same number of output as blank even the data is not there in Table in SSRS report?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I have a report where i am passing some ID's as parameter in one report.

My requirement is IF i am passing 10 Id's as parameter ,I should get 10 records in the report.
Suppose for ID 3,the data is not present in the table.Then i should get the ID 3 in the report with blank columns.

OR

May be we can put one text box in the report with message like No data for these ID's

If we can do in the first way,that will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Regards
sshh0988

Comment: Learn how to properly post your questions. Give information about your tables, give the code you are working on and the result you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could try taking the list of parameters and setting up a dataset that will return them to you in a table and using this table in the result set, so you can LEFT OUTER JOIN your results to the list of supplied parameters. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @MyParameters VARCHAR(Max)
DECLARE @Separator VARCHAR(10)
SET @MyParameters = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10'
SET @Separator = ','


DECLARE @Found as VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TableList TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(MAX))

SET @Separator = ISNULL(@Separator,',')

    -- Check whether the @MyParameters parameter is a single value or a concatenated list. SSRS will deliver a comma seperated list if
    -- more than one organisation is selected
    IF CHARINDEX(@Separator,@MyParameters) <> 0

    -- If the @MyParameters is actually a concatenated list, we need to split it out into seperate names, which is achieved with a loop:
        BEGIN
            RinseAndRepeat:
            -- If there are no more seperators in the list then we must have got to the last value in the list
            IF CHARINDEX(@Separator,@MyParameters) = 0 
                BEGIN
                    -- Set our most recent value to whatever remains in the list (i.e. the last value in the list)
                    SET @Found = @MyParameters
                    -- Add the value to the table containing all values from the list
                    INSERT INTO @TableList VALUES (@Found)
                END
            -- If there is still at least one seperator in the list, there is more than one value left, so we need to take one off the front of the list
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    IF LEFT(@MyParameters,LEN(@Separator)) = @Separator
                        -- If there is a seperator on the front of the remaining list, take it off.
                        SET @MyParameters = RIGHT(@MyParameters, LEN(@MyParameters)-LEN(@Separator))

                    -- Take from the start of the list up to the next seperator (not including the seperator itself)
                    SET @Found = SUBSTRING(@MyParameters,0,CHARINDEX(@Separator,@MyParameters))
                    -- Update the list to not include the most recently taken value, nor the seperator that follows it
                    SET @MyParameters = SUBSTRING(@MyParameters,LEN(@Found)+ 1 + LEN(@Separator),LEN(@MyParameters))
                    -- Add the found value to the table of all found values
                    INSERT INTO @TableList VALUES (@Found)
                    -- Go back and look at the next term, which is now at the start of the list
                    GOTO RinseAndRepeat
                END
        END
    -- If the @MyParameters parameter is not a concatenated list, then just take that name and put it in the name list table.
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @TableList VALUES(@MyParameters)
        END

------------------------------------------------------------------
-- whatever you do to get your results
DECLARE @Results TABLE (Id INT NOT NULL, Value VARCHAR(10))
INSERT @Results VALUES (1,'One')
INSERT @Results VALUES (2,'Two')
INSERT @Results VALUES (6,'Six')
INSERT @Results VALUES (9,'Nine')
INSERT @Results VALUES (10,'Ten')

SELECT MyParam.Value AS Id , Results.Value
FROM
                @TableList  MyParam
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Results    Results ON MyParam.Value = Results.Id
```

Now your dataset will always have one row for each parameter supplied, with values only where a matching value is returned. SSRS will by default provide multi-select parameters as a comma separated list like that shown above. Of course, the null returned values can be dealt with as you wish

For your option B, there is the possibility to enter a "No Data Message" for a table or region - see [this link for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220407.aspx).